# Ho to filter on linq queryes c# by key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

i want to filter my query using c# and EF Core so that from this list:

```json
{
  "result": [
    {
      "commissionId": "b99a0152-b3a5-4ff6-f19e-08da6a45d751",
      "commissionCode": "0001",
      "commissionDescription": "Description1",
      "activityId": "323e6237-c3f6-4616-3117-08da6a28ad38",
      "activityCode": "01.1",
      "activityDescription": "DELETE FILE",
      "minuteWorked": 10440,
      "activityList": null,
      "timeWorked": "7.06:00:00"
    },
    {
      "commissionId": "b99a0152-b3a5-4ff6-f19e-08da6a45d751",
      "commissionCode": "0001",
      "commissionDescription": "Description1",
      "activityId": "95d37329-acac-4443-3118-08da6a28ad38",
      "activityCode": "01.2",
      "activityDescription": "DOWNLOAD FILE",
      "minuteWorked": 15,
      "activityList": null,
      "timeWorked": "00:15:00"
    },
    {
      "commissionId": "b99a0152-b3a5-4ff6-f19e-08da6a45d751",
      "commissionCode": "0001",
      "commissionDescription": "Description1",
      "activityId": "89fd1d93-b5b8-4c08-3119-08da6a28ad38",
      "activityCode": "01.3",
      "activityDescription": "FILE SAVE",
      "minuteWorked": 0,
      "activityList": null,
      "timeWorked": "00:00:00"
    },
```

I get this:

```json
{
  "result": [
    {
      "commissionId": "b99a0152-b3a5-4ff6-f19e-08da6a45d751",
      "commissionCode": "0001",
      "commissionDescription": "Description1",
      "activityList": "{ 323e6237-c3f6-4616-3117-08da6a28ad38",95d37329-acac-4443-3118- 
                       08da6a28ad38,89fd1d93-b5b8-4c08-3119-08da6a28ad38 }
      "timeWorked": "7.06:00:00"
    },
```

---

Just to clarify the first list is obtained doing a:

- `GroupBy( c => new {c.ActivityId, c.CommissionId}`
- And then:

```cs
Select(grp => new RegistrationStatisticViewModel() {CommissionId = grp.Key.CommissionId,
         CommissionCode = grp.First().Commission.Code,
         CommissionDescription = grp.First().Commission.Description,
         ActivityId = grp.Key.ActivityId,
         ActivityCode = grp.First().Activity.Code,
         ActivityDescription = grp.First().Activity.Description,
         MinuteWorked = grp.Sum(c => c.MinuteWorked)
         })
         .ToListAsync(),
```

The second list essentially groups all `Commission` with the same `id` and then i guess ? it has a property of type `List<T>` that stores all the `activityId`.

So i want to group all the activity for one commissionId but only have one commissionCode etc.

Thanks to whoever replies!

Comment: so what you want is to be grouped by commision id? then you can try var groupedResult = result.GroupBy(g=>g.commissionId).ToList(); so here, the key will be commissionId

Comment: Yeah i want my list to group all the activity from one commission. Because right now i am getting commission duplicates.

Comment: The thing is that in my list i could have multiple commission or the same commission say twice but with different activities

Comment: yes, so for the different commissions you will get different groups.

Comment: Show full query, not just `Select` part. Usually when people do mistake with joins, they have duplicates.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i have Commission object duplicates because in my case it is possible that one commissionId has more ActivityId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
            grp
            .ToList()
            .Where(cm => cm.CommissionId = CommissionId)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(c =>
            {
                grp.activityList.Add(c.activityId);
            });
```

NOTE: untested code.

Comment: Where should i put it then? after `Select()`?

Comment: Replace your "ActivityId = grp.Key.ActivityId,"...you want a list of id`s and not just one. Also remove "ActivityDescription = grp.First().Activity.Description," because it makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But now where do you get that `cm` ?

Comment: I did this `.Where(grp.Key.CommissionId == CommissionId)` It says the name `CommissionId` does not exists in the current context...

Comment: Save your first list on some var called grp and then assign grp to the code I`ve provided. After all that, build your view model.